# Загрузка с периодическим выходом

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Здравствуйте. Нужна помощь с написанием скрипта. У моего интернета такая особенность: в начале загрузки скорость даже больше, чем указано в ограничении (ограничено 7 КБ, а в начале достигает и 20 КБ), но потом постепенно падает до нескольких сот байт. Нужно написать shell-файл, в котором повторялся данный участок кода:

```
wget -c filesleep 10
```

Я не знаю:

1. Как организовать выход из wget
2. Как организовать цикл
3. И как его завершить, если файл скачается

Помогите кто чем сможет.

Comment: Не очень понятно что вы хотите, пока понял что что то типа download manager. Вы хотите при маленькой скорости загрузку прекращать, и запускать заново, но с того момента на котором прекратили? Распишите по подробнее задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Что мешает наличествующий скрипт запускать через Cron? Добавьте его в задания и на этом все, данные по работе скрипта загоняйте в лог - будете видеть что происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Наблюдал похожую особенность на "своём" интернете. Придумал объяснение. Программе, которая определяет скорость, необходимы данные для статистики и чем их больше, тем точнее результат. В начале, если скорость подключения высокая и искусственно ограничивается на единицу времени, то, например, за 1/3 от неё (условной единицы, пусть в 1 сек.) может быть скачано 7 Кб, а в оставшиеся 2/3 - 0. Таким образом на малом объёме данных выдаётся одна статистика, а со временем приближается к более точному среднему значению. Причём "пики", скорее всего предусмотреть и просчитать нельзя, поэтому "ловить волну" не получится (и даже в случае успеха, в остальное время скорость будет понижаться до соответствия лимиту, так, что общий результат останется неизменным).